# Cannot convert "list" data to "integer" or "numeric" in R

Tags: r

I am reading in data from an SPSS .sav file on R (I do not have access to the CSV or XLSX file). I am trying to do analyses with mirt. However, the data type is "list", and I cannot get it to change to "integer" or "numeric". There is one column with text and the rest are 0s and 1s. However, I have tried this on a subset of the data which contains only 0s and 1s and have had the same issue. I get this error message when I read in the data:

Warning messages:
1: Values in `accuracy` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.

I have tried the as.data.frame command, the data.frame command, and the as.numeric command, but every time I call "typeof" it still tells me "list".

Can anyone tell me how to convert these data to integer or numeric? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kAyY.png) Here is an image of the data.

And the structure from the "dput" call: 
structure(list(Username = c("lga_tso19", "lga_tso2", "lga_tso20", 
"lga_tso21", "lga_tso22", "lga_tso24", "lga_tso26", "lga_tso27"
), NEO_C_Q01 = structure(c(5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5), label = "Always prepared", labels = c(`Very inaccurate` = 1, 
`Moderately inaccurate` = 2, `Neither accurate nor inaccurate` = 3, 
`Moderately accurate` = 4, `Very accurate` = 5), class = "haven_labelled"), structure(list(`77` = list(structure(0, label = "User Respond Correctly?", labels = c(No = 0, 
Yes = 1), class = "haven_labelled"), structure(1, label = "User Respond Correctly?", labels = c(No = 0, 
Yes = 1), class = "haven_labelled"), structure(0, label = "User Respond Correctly?", labels = c(No = 0, 
Yes = 1), class = "haven_labelled"), structure(0, label = "User Respond Correctly?", labels = c(No = 0, 
Yes = 1), class = "haven_labelled"))

So far, I have attempted unlist(data), as.data.frame(data), data.frame(data), and write.csv(data). When I do unlist() and then typeof() it changes the data to "double", and when I try to run the following on a subset of this data:
2PL<-mirt(baggage, "2PL")

I get this message:

Error in model$x[i, "Type"] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In cbind(model$x, OptionalGroups = "") :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

Comment: try `unlist(your_list)`

Comment: It might be difficult (for some of us, at least) to help if we don't know what the object looks like. Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Hi @RileyH, Can you please add a snapshot of your data. It'll be more easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help! I have added some more details that should make my question more clear.